# dllexport Struct pointers and returning uint8_t

Tags: c#, c, visual-c++, dllexport

I am creating a c wrapper library to be used in a c# application. In my .c, the function is defined:

```
__declspec(dllexport) uint8_t aes132h_nonce(struct aes132h_nonce_in_out *param)
{ 
 // do something
 return 0; 
}
```

In my C#, how do I define the function, which takes a pointer to a struct and returns a `uint8_t`?

```
    [DllImport("AesHelperLib.dll")]
    public static extern uint8_t aes132h_nonce(ref aes132h_nonce_in_out *param);
```

Do I need to create the struct with proper padding and alignment in c# or is there a way to export the struct `aes132h_nonce_in_out` so i can use the struct in c#? Also, how to define the return type as `uint8_t` is not a valid type in c#?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to create the struct with proper padding and alignment in c#

Essentially, yes: There’s no way of using C struct declarations directly in C#, and there’s no 1:1 mapping. Beware that if you declare the parameter in your DLL import as `ref` then you shouldn’t also make it a pointer.

In some cases, e.g. when just “passing through” a value between API calls, you can also just declare the parameter as (in this case, pass by value) `IntPtr` and treat its contents as an opaque type.

> Also, how to define the return type as `uint8_t` is not a valid type in c#?

The [interop best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices) say to use the closest equvialent .NET type — in this case, `byte`.